# How to change style of multiple div on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, zooming

I need to change style of multiple divs on click of a button that have the same name.I have the button where I create div with image.

This is code for creating the div

```
function creatContent(e) {
var divMark = document.createElement("div");
divMark.classList = `markers mark`;

var img = $('<img class="comment" src="indeksiraj-1.png" alt="myimage" />');

$(divMark).append(img);
$(marksCanvas).append(divMark);
}
```

When I create div I can drag that div on browser.Now I need to change the style of div but when I create two div or more when I press the button I change style just of the last div other div stay the same.

This is code for everything:

```
var xCord;
var yCord;
var xLeft = 0;
var yTop = 0;

function creatContent(e) {
var divMark = document.createElement("div");
divMark.classList = `markers mark`;

var img = $('<img class="comment" src="indeksiraj-1.png" alt="myimage" />');

$(divMark).append(img);

window.onload = addListeners();

function addListeners() {
    divMark.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e) {
    xCord = e.pageX;
    yCord = e.pageY;
    divMark.style.top = yCord + "px";
    divMark.style.left = xCord + "px";
}

zoomIn.onclick = function () {
    var myImg = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;

    if (currWidth == 1200) return false;
    else {
        myImg.style.width = currWidth + 100 + "px";
    }

    xLeft += xCord + 25;
    yTop += yCord + 22;

    divMark.style.left = xLeft + "px";
    divMark.style.top = yTop + "px";

    xLeft -= xCord;
    yTop -= yCord;
};

zoomOutBtn.onclick = function () {
    var myImg = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
    var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
    if (currWidth == 800) return false;
    else {
        myImg.style.width = currWidth - 100 + "px";
    }
    xLeft += xCord - 25;
    yTop += yCord - 22;

    divMark.style.left = xLeft + "px";
    divMark.style.top = yTop + "px";

    xLeft -= xCord;
    yTop -= yCord;
};
}
```

This is demo https://jsfiddle.net/SutonJ/5gyqexhj/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are referring to `divmark` at the `movediv` function you are referring to the last div you made.
Instead you should refer to a class of that div since all of the divs you made have the same classes if I understand correctly.
So you can use jquery to add the style to the class like so:

```
$('.markers').css({'top': yCord + "px", 'left': xCord + "px"})
```

That will add the styling to all the elements that have the class `markers`.
If you have other elements with that class that you do not want to have those styles then you should add a unique class for those divs you made at `divmark.classList`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.getElementsByClassName('<name of class>')`

That way all the divs with the class name  will be affected by the event.